# How to tunnel all the traffic for one interface through another interface

Tags: 20.04, iptables, openvpn, wireguard

I have two working interfaces on my ubuntu `machine`:

- `tun0` - OpenVPN server with the internal address of: 10.8.0.0/24
- `wg0` - WireGuard peer interface with the internal address of: 10.7.0.0/24 which is connected to an external WireGuard server with a successful handshake.

And I'm trying to tunnel all the requests for `tun0` through `wg0`. So when I connect to the OpenVPN tunnel, it would be as if I'm connected to the WireGuard server.

And this is how my `iptables` backup looks like before making any changes:

```
*filter
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS
COMMIT
```

So by looking at this I figured if I replaced the `MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS` with the internal IP of WireGuard connection it might work:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.7.0.0
```

Which did not work. I also tried:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -o wg0
```

And in both cases, the OpenVPN connection was established but fully timed out.

Is there a way I can achieve this without too much configuration?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to me like a "reverse proxy" behavior, you could use [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) or  nginx for this, I think it should be fairly easy, something like:

```
caddy reverse-proxy --from 10.8.0.0:2080 --to 10.7.0.0:9000
```

With iptables, I'm not so sure but I found:

https://serverfault.com/questions/1025857/iptables-as-a-reverse-proxy

Which seems very similar to your solutions, but it seems they map one port at a time, did you try to map a specific port?